# Dissapearing dots when with errors.add in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a model in rails.
It is used to store Network devices with IP and subnet information.
One thing it should do is to check if the IP of the device is in the respective subnet, and display a fancy error if it's not.

The validation itself works great but the error message misses the dots of the IP address.
The relevant parts of my code are:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subnet

  validates :subnet, :presence => true

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :subnet_id}
  validates :IP, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :subnet_id}
  validates :MAC, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :subnet_id}
  validates_format_of :MAC, :with => /\A([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\z/i
  validate :isInSub

...

private

def isInSub
    unless NetAddr::CIDR.create(self.subnet.CIDR.to_str,Version:4).matches?(self.IP.to_str)
        errors.add(self.IP.to_str, "is not in the Subnet #{self.subnet.CIDR.to_str}")
    end
    rescue
        errors.add(self.IP.to_str, "is no valid IP")
        print(self.IP.to_str)   <--- This output has the dots!
end
```

So if something goes wrong while "making" the IP address I add a generic "is invalid" error.
But when the IP is correct, but not in the subnet, then I add a different error.

The validation itself works and I get error messages in my form, but the IP is not displayed correctly. The dots are missing, but only from the IP address - from the Subnet CIDR they are there.

So the error should look like this

### 1 error prohibited
        this device from being saved:

- 192.168.2.255 is not in the Subnet 192.168.1.1/24

But it looks like this

### 1 error prohibited
        this device from being saved:

- 192 168 2 255 is not in the Subnet 192.168.1.1/24

The problem occurs with both error messages, but in the `print` I added as debug the dots are still there.

Is there a way to fix this without opening myself up to all sorts of injection attacks?

Comment: What is the data type of the CIDR & IP ??

Comment: In the subnet model the CIDR is defined as a string. And NetAddr parses the string to do the "network-stuff". I guess I could leave the `to_str` for the CIDR.   
And IP is also a string in the model

Comment: The problem is with IP from Devise, what is the datatype of it?

Comment: The IP from the Device is also a string. So I should be able to leave out the `to_str` for it too...

Comment: Try `errors.add(:base, "#{self.IP.to_str} is not in the Subnet #{self.subnet.CIDR.to_str}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails calls `errors.full_messages` when displaying the list of errors which humanizes the attribute which in this case is `192.168.2.255`, so the dots are removed. 
You can properly add the attribute to errors i.e.

```
errors.add(:IP, "#{self.IP.to_str} is not in the Subnet #{self.subnet.CIDR.to_str}")
```

That should generate an error message like below

**IP 192.168.2.255 is not in the Subnet 192.168.1.1/24**

Comment: That worked, Thanks!  
But is the #-method a "good practice" ?  
I used it for the CIDR, since it comes from my DB and is cleaned before, but the IP is direct User input, so is it "secure"?

Comment: #-method just interpolates the value into the string so it's totally fine, since you're already accessing the same value above for validating. You need to be careful when passing user input values directly into custom sql queries.